# Which of the following is NOT required to convert a POJO into an entity?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Which of the following is NOT required to convert a POJO into an entity?

- a.DAO
- b.JPQL
- c.Annotations
- d.EntityManager API

Being a learner in ejb I came across this question in one of the certification exam questions and became inquisitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the only thing that turns a POJO into an entity is **c. Annotations**. The others are just:

- **DAO:** design pattern for abstracting the database access logic.
- **JPQL:** Query language that performs queries on entities as opposed to SQL which queries on tables. Eventually JPQL gets converted to SQL though.
- **EntityManager:** in charge of handling entities in terms of database interactions. Is able to e.g. persist, merge, remove entities.

But considering that the question asks for just **one** element, I would discard DAO which is just a design pattern and not part of the Java EE spec. It is also not necessary to manage entities.

My two cents.

Comment: Hehe.....thank you....may be the question can be  most appropriately framed as which among the options is most wrong or most irrelevent :P